# Playstation network signed me out?

Tags: ps4, psn, ps5

So I recently turned on my PS4 & my PSN account was signed out, unfortunately I don't know my password nor do I have access to the email address associated with the account. I've never experienced this before though so I'm curious as to why my account was signed out? My account has remained logged into without requiring authentication for over a year..

So I have three questions,

#1 - If I were to be banned from PSN for whatever reason, would I have been logged out automatically, or would I be prompted with a dialogue stating I'm banned.

#2 - Is this normal? Is it a regular occurence for you to be randomly signed out of PSN ( I mean I would assume not, since I've been logged in for over a year.

#3 - Is it possible someone changed my password whilst I was inactive? and so due to crednetials changing I was signed out to reauthenticate my credentials.

Comment: Are you able to navigate your profile and are just unable to access PSN, or are you unable to use your profile at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you were inactive, sometimes the console will prompt for your password to check up on security preferences, and to make sure it is you. I find it happens about every 6-12 months (even if I'm active), but that is just a guess on my part. Normally, I am able to still browse on my profile and see my Games and Apps, but just unable to use PSN services.

If you do not know your password and do not have the email, I am not sure what you can do to access the PSN account.

Answer (score 0):

The only times I remember being signed out of PSN suddenly, are:

- When there's been an error on my network
- When there's been a more generalised PSN crash/error (usually [more than one player](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/92k919/randomly_signed_out_of_psn/) experiences this)
- When PSN has updated itself and the [TOS](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/legal/psn-terms-of-service/) have changed

If you don't have the password or access to the email account, you're pretty screwed. Unless you can message and convince PSN staff that you did have access to the email until recently, but lost it for whatever reason. But that is a very optimistic outlook.

*Question #1*

> ### How do I know if my account or console has been suspended from PSN?
>
> If we suspend your account or PlayStation console, you will see an error code when
> attempting to sign in to PSN.
>
> We usually email you explaining why you've been suspended and how long it will last.
> We send that to the email address associated with your account (your sign-in ID). Be
> sure to check your junk or spam folder for the email.

[- PlayStation suspension info](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/support/account/suspensions-psn/)

Comment: If you downvote, please comment as to [why](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) :) (The rambling accusations has been removed and it looks like a helpful answer to me(?))

Comment: This is a good answer, but try to answer all of the O.P's questions, it looks better.